# Costmap's obstacle does not clear properly under sparse environment

Tags: navigation, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I would like to use Hokuyo to perform navigation under outdoor environment (open field for example). However, the obstacles detected before is not clearing out although the laser shows that there's no object. There is some hack that I can use for example http://answers.ros.org/question/1375/how-to-clear-older-costmap-just-before-updating but is there a more elegant way to do this? Perhaps through some parameter settings?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11446/costmap%27s-obstacle-does-not-clear-properly-under-sparse-environment/) by [Demian](https://answers.ros.org/users/1183/demian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-10-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Demian](https://answers.ros.org/users/1183/demian/) on 2011-10-07**:
Ah, yes, the UTM-30LX is exactly the one we are using. So far so good even under direct sunlight. Can anyone shed some light to the way the costmap does the clearing?

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2011-10-07**:
Oh yes, I forgot to make that distinction. I apologize.

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2011-10-06**:
That depends, the URG models are basically non-usable in sunlight, but the UTM-30LX worked ok for us so far.

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2011-10-06**:
I know this isn't an answer, but I must warn you, in direct sunlight, I've determined that the Hokuyo scanner performs very poorly. It wasn't even feasible for us to use because of it's performance. I know this is just our analysis, but it could be a problem for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't believe there is any more elegant way.

When clearing obstacles, `costmap_2d` only trusts laser scans returning a definite range. Indoors, that makes sense. Outdoors, most scans return max range, which does not clear intervening obstacles. A fake scan with slightly shorter ranges can be constructed that does clear them out.

That hack is messy, but not particularly difficult.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) on 2011-10-07**:
This is something that's come up a few times. Missing returns don't always imply max range so the navigation stack makes no assumptions about them by default. As Jack suggested, the easiest thing to do is write a filter that inserts measurements into a clearing scan at some range.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is an option in the costmap sensor parameters that allows inf values to be treated as valid. See http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/hydro/obstacles
Section 1.2.2

~/<source_name>/inf_is_valid (bool, default: false)

---

Originally posted by [mgerdzhev](https://answers.ros.org/users/20158/mgerdzhev/) with karma: 43 on 2015-05-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2015-05-01**:
Thanks for mentioning that. It was not available back in 2011.